# Bootstrap Nav suddenly stopped working - no code changed

Tags: asp.net, razor, model-view-controller, bootstrapping

I am building a web application in asp.net MVC. My bootstrap navbar was working perfectly yesterday. When I run things in debug there are no errors. No code has been changed on the layout. I recently tried doing an href to the bootstrap repo with no luck. I'm not asking you to debug my code, because their shouldn't be any errors. Why could this be happening?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Employee Portal</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>


    <!--================== NAVBAR ===================-->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                @Html.ActionLink("Employee Portal", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Add Employee", "Create", "Employees")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("All Employees", "Index", "Employees")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("All Positions", "Index", "Positions")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("All Departments", "Index", "Departments")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Reports", "Reports", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Employee Activity", "Index", "ChangeLogs")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- End NAVBAR-->



    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Conservice</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is in the `~/bundles/bootstrap` bundle? And why do you need it if you also directly link to the bootstrap.js file? And when you say "it's not working", please be specific, what exactly is happening?

Comment: Did you accidentally upgrade to Bootstrap 4 in Nuget?

Comment: I only directly linked to the bootstrap.js file in case the referencing to the bootstrap bundle that contains all the bootstrap files was not working correctly. @IrishChieftain That could be very possible; Do you have a recommended fix?

Comment: Check the version currently in your project. If that is what happened you can easily revert to 3.x in the Nuget UI.

Comment: @IrishChieftain Indeed it is version 4.0. Reverted to 3.7, still viewing the same. How do I know which version is applicable to the navbar I had originally?

Comment: I don't know the details of your site. However, the production version of 4.x just went live so in all probability your site was based on 3.x. The CDN you're referencing in your layout file is 4.x

Comment: Unfortunately reverting to different versions is still giving me the same looking output. I even tried updating to 4.0 and using a sample from https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/ - but it still looks incorrect.

Comment: Saying it "looks incorrect" is not helpful, how can anyone try to help you fix that?

Comment: Agreed @DavidG. I ended up creating an entirely new application and copying over all code. Long solution to a simple problem. I must have updated multiple packages that caused issues. It's been awhile since I have been on Stack Overflow - how do I mark  answer as correct? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood, your Nuget Bootstrap version got updated. I also notice that you're referring to Bootstrap 4.0 [CDN](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/) in your layout file. Reverting to Bootstrap 3.x via the Nuget UI and correcting the CDN link should fix your problem.

The Navbar in the new version 4 of Bootstrap is a breaking change.

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#navbar